# How to check if File exists in the Dropbox account of a certain user using Dropbox iOS SDK 1.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am currently developing an application which is using the *Dropbox iOS SDK version 1.1.* I am developing the application for iOS version 5.0 and above. I went through all the methods in the *DBRestClient.h* file which is included in the SDK. I could not find a method which allowed me to check whether a given file exists in a given location in a directory. I was thinking if I could use the following method in the *DBRestClient.h* file to do the same

```
- (void)loadMetadata:(NSString*)path;
```

Here, I thought of using the Location/FileName in the Path parameter to find out whether the given file existed or not.

I am not at all sure about the correct approach for doing the same. Please suggest some better methods if this is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox SDK does not support search (it only supports a subset of the Dropbox API). To do what you need effenciently, call the search method of the REST API directly

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#search

If you want to stick with the SDK, you can call loadMetadata recursively for each folder level until you find the file you are looking for. But I do not recommend this (imagine if your user is on the cell network as you make tens or hundreds of calls).